# Preventing users clicking same correct answer twice in multiple choice question (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a course/quiz application in ReactJS. One of the components I am making is a multiple choice question however, the user will be able to select 2 correct answers instead of just 1.
Currently in my code, it counts how many clicks the user has done and when it hits 2 it will disable the buttons. However, if the user selects the same right answer twice, it counts as 2 correct answers.

How would I be able to stop the user from doing this?

**MultipleAnswer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './MultipleAnswers.scss'


//Shuffle Answer Array

function shuffleArray(array) {
    let i = array.length - 1;
    for (; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  


export default class MultipleAnswers extends Component {

state = {
    unshuffledAnswers: [ { answer: this.props.answer, right: true }, { answer: this.props.wrongAnswer, right: false }, {answer: this.props.wrongAnswer2, right: false}, {answer: this.props.answer2, right: true} ],
    shuffledAnswers: [],
    clicks: 0
}


componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        shuffledAnswers: shuffleArray(this.state.unshuffledAnswers)
    })
}


handleAnswer = (Answer) => {
    this.props.AnswerClicked(Answer)

    this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks +1
    })

    if (this.state.clicks >= 1) {
        this.setState({
            disabled: true
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            disabled: false
        })
    }

}



render() {

const shuffledAnswers = this.state.shuffledAnswers

    return (
            <div className = "MultipleChoice">
                <h1> Multiple Answers </h1>
                <form>
                    <label className = "Question"> {this.props.question}  </label>
                        {shuffledAnswers.map((answer) => {
                            return (
                                <div className = "Answer">
                                <input type = "button" disabled = {this.state.disabled} name = {this.props.question} value = {answer.answer} onClick = {() => {this.handleAnswer(answer.right)}}/> 
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep your question Id, and answer Id on your state and handle change do a  check if the same question answer is already added previously. Then you can calculate if you need to disable or enable based on the question and selected answer from the state.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` in async, so when you read `this.state` in `handleAnswer` right after calling `setState` it hasn't been populated yet.

One way around this is to read the state, then set new values at once:

```
const clicks = this.state.clicks + 1

this.setState({
    clicks,
    disabled: clicks >= 1
})
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-rgb-lvtun?file=/src/App.js:930-1064)

Comment: What does disabled serves for?

Comment: This is helpful but unfortunately doesn't answer my question since it still allows the user to select the same correct answer twice. Thank you anyway!